# Implementing SSE with oat++

Tags: oat++

I would like to use Server Side Event or HTTP long polling with oat++, but i didn't found any documentation or example on how to implement it. Is it possible (with some example, please) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already answered in this [issue](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/issues/742)